# Save Mode when writing Parquet files and saving as partitioned table

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, parquet, azure-databricks

When I write a data frame to an existing location without specifying the save mode it returns an error

```
df.write.partitionBy("column").option("path", <EXISTING PATH>).format("parquet").save
```

However, when I execute the same command just with saveAsTable option then, if the table doesn't exist, Spark appears to overwrite the data.

```
df.write.partitionBy("column").option("path", <EXISTING PATH>).format("parquet").saveAsTable(<NEW_TABLE>)
```

Can anyone provide an explanation of this logic. What actually happens under the hood?

I'm working on Databricks.

**EDIT**

Following Aravind's comment I added the missing `save` method to the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will be returning a dataFrameWriter, instead of writing into specified path.

```
df.write.partitionBy("column").option("path", <EXISTING PATH>).format("parquet")
```

To write a dataframe by partition to a specified path using save() function consider below code,

```
df.write.partitionBy("column").format("parquet").save("<EXISTING PATH>/df.parquet")
```

To write a dataframe by partition to a specified path using saveAsTable() function consider your code,

```
df.write.partitionBy("column").option("path", <EXISTING PATH>).format("parquet").saveAsTable(<NEW_TABLE>)
```

coming back to your question, Let it be save() function or saveAsTable() function default saveMode will be **errorIfExists**.

For more information on save() or saveAsTable() or saveMode go through [DataFrameWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter).

Comment: Thanks, I missed the save method. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

As Aranvid correctly pointed out the Save method and the SaveAsTable do different checks.

The SaveAsTable of the DataFrameWriter checks just the existence of the table in the Hive catalog and throws a  `new AnalysisException(s"Table $tableIdent already exists.")`. On the other hand, the Save table checks just if the path exists. More specifically, it uses the run method of the class `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand` that triggers an `AnalysisException` if the path exists and no SaveMode has been specified.

I don't know why Spark developers made such a distinction, my guess is that in one case you are operating at Hive level, so you 'trust' the Hive catalog on the other at file system level so you 'trust' the file system (thus throw an error if the path exists).

Comment: Thanks both. I edited my initial post. I should also have mentioned that I'm working on Azure Databricks. Can we conclude then, that save() by default returns an error whereas saveAsTable() overwrites? Also, the former do check the file location whereas the latter merely the table name?

Comment: SaveAsTable() also won't overwrite unless saveMode is explicitly mentioned. It'll throw an AnalysisException as LizardKing said.

Comment: Yer Dawid, that would be my conclusion. Working on Databricks does not change things. The players are the same, it still uses Spark, a distributed file system and an internal (or external) Hive Metastore.  I have made some checks on Databricks and I have found the same behavior you noticed.